# use swr hook: avoid first call to refresh token on interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch, swr

I have a refresh token call using swr every x minutes. All tokens are stored in local storage and retrieved from there to the token states in my application. After this, the refresh token is called immediately, like this:

```js
useSWR(
  isAuthenticated ? "/api/v1/refresh-token" : null,
  async (url) => axios
    .post(url, { refreshToken }, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    })
    .then((result) => result.data),
  {
    refreshInterval: x, // <-- every x minutes (ms)
    onSuccess: (session) => {
      setToken(session.access_token)
      setRefreshToken(session.refresh_token)
    })
  }
)
```

I want to call the refresh token every x minutes but avoiding the first time when the page is reloaded (token states are set).

Is there any easy way to do it? (maybe with a swr option idk), without for example, write an useEffect who sets a boolean `canRefresh` to true after x minutes ... I really don't like this solution, use a counter state neither.

Any smart proposal on this?

Comment: Maybe as simple as `setTimeout`?

Comment: It seems to be the solution I proposed, write an useEffect which changes the state `canRefresh` after x minutes (using setTimeout). LMK if I'm wrong

Comment: I would just ditch `useSWR` altogether. It's usecase it fetching. Right away. With cache and all the fancy stuff that comes with it. If that's not what you need, then why try to force it to do something else.